# Javascript and Firefox 4 issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox4

The code below works fine in FF3.X and IE7 to 9, but not in FF4.

I have this code in 2 places in my file:

```
                var arguments = "method=getoptions";
                arguments += "&dropzone=" + dictKey;
                arguments += "&format=disc";
                arguments += "&datasetid=" + datasetid;
                arguments += "&varnumber=" + varnumber;
                arguments += "&varSectionId=" + varSectionId;
                arguments += "&catindex=" + catIndex;
                arguments += "&defaultid=dv_cat_opts_default_body";
                arguments += "&mmocid=dv_cat_opts_mmoc_body";

                 alert(arguments);
```

which produces

```
               method=getoptions&dropzone=Row_1&format=disc&datasetid=1&varnumber=206&varSectionId=FUV&catindex=&defaultid=dv_cat_opts_default_body&mmocid=dv_cat_opts_mmoc_body
```

and that is correct, but the same code elsewhere in the file

```
                 var arguments = "method=getoptions";
                arguments += "&dropzone=" + dictKey;
                arguments += "&format=disc";
                arguments += "&datasetid=" + datasetid;
                arguments += "&varnumber=" + varnumber;
                arguments += "&varSectionId=" + varSectionId;
                arguments += "&catindex=" + catIndex;
                arguments += "&defaultid=dv_cat_opts_default_body";
                arguments += "&mmocid=dv_cat_opts_mmoc_body";

                 alert(arguments);
```

outputs this which ends up calling an error in my ajax:

```
             [object Arguments]&dropzone=Row_1&format=cont&datasetid=1&varnumber=1125&varSectionId=FUV&catindex=&defaultid=dv_cont_opts_default_body&mmocid=dv_cont_opts_mmoc_body
```

So what's the deal with that object Arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `arguments` is a special object available within functions, it contains all the arguments passed to a function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/functions_and_function_scope/arguments

To put it another way, consider the variable name `arguments` to be a reserved keyword - just like you would never name a variable `if`, **don't use the variable name `arguments` or you will get unexpected results.**

Why is this thing here, you might ask - it lets you write your functions that use a varying number and order of arguments.  Within your function, you'd write code to determine which arguments were passed and what they are.  It takes quite a bit more code, but you can create some pretty flexible reusable code with this technique.  Check out some of the internal functions for Mootools or jQuery and you'll see that these popular frameworks make heavy use of the `arguments` object.

Consider:

```
function alertError() {
 var exception = false;
 var message = false;
 for( var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++ ) {
  if (typeof arguments[i] == 'object')
    exception = arguments[i];
  if (typeof arguments[i] == 'string')
    message = arguments[i];
 }

 if (message == false)
   message = 'No details';
 if (exception != false)
   message += ', exception: '+exception.message;

 alert('There has been an error: '+message);
}
alertError("No exceptions here!");
try {
 var t = t.doesnotexist;
} catch (e) {
 alertError(e, 'Testing');
}
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/zwGMJ/

Comment: Although that doesn't explain the OP's result, which I can't reproduce (although I do get warnings that redeclaration of and assignment to arguments is deprecated).

Comment: Yes, it does explain the OP's results.  The text "[object Arguments]&dropzone=Row_1&" makes it clear he has tried to treat the variable `arguments` as a string.

Comment: we @neil, both set of code were in the same function but in if loops so they have local scope.  @chris, changed the var arguments to var arg and it works. Interesting tho that it works in other browsers and works sometimes in ff4?

Comment: Because the implementation of javascript is different per user agent, different browsers are going to have implemented and adopted this at different times and in different ways. I suspect you aren't the only one to be have been caught by surprise when a browser released an update and it started doing things differently :)

Comment: true but why does it work in ff4 and also not work when its the same code?

Comment: Without having seen the code in context and in the original state, hard to say.  Maybe the first time you used it was in a different scope, maybe you omitted a `var arguments` statement the first time, so you got the error, by the time the second batch of code came up, the variable had already been converted implicitly into a string... hard to say man.  That's why I used the lawyerly phrase "get unexpected results" instead of saying "It won't work".  It might work sometimes, it might kind of work... unexpected and unpredictable results.

Comment: too true, probably gets implictedly converted somewhere, thx! :)

Comment: What I meant was, that if he was actually seeing `[object Arguments]` then he must have failed to initially assign to arguments, but neither of his examples show that happening.

Answer (score 1):

`arguments` is a reserved variable in JavaScript functions, which contains the arguments (also known as parameters) of the function. 
So, for example, `function(a){alert(a);}` would be the same as `function(){alert(arguments[0]);}`. 
To fix this error, simply change the variable's name to something else.

Ad@m